# Does completeness imply the completeness axiom?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is an ordered field. Suppose that there exists a bounded subset of $X$ having no least upper bound. Does there exist a metric $d$ on $X$, such that $(X,d)$ is complete?

Comment: It's clear that you mean it, but to avoid trivialities (discrete metric) you should say that you mean a metric inducing the order topology.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The ordered set $Q$ of rational numbers violates the lub property and is not completely metrizable, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_metrizable_space).

Edit: The title of your question suggests that you are interested in the opposite direction: Does complete metrizability of an order topology imply the lub property for the order.

The answer to this is negative: Take the complement $X$ to a point in the real line: The lub property is violated in $X$, but $X$ is homeomorphic to the union of two distinct parallel lines in the plane and, hence, is completely metrizable.

Comment: But the complement of a point is not a field. As I understand it, the question is whether an ordered field that is completely metrisable must have the least upper bound property.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh, I see: I missed the assumption that it is a field.